# Meaning of "euoluemus"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

On pg 340 of Gauss' *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* (chapter 235) is the phrase "et quae inde sequantur euoluemus".  What does this word "euoluemus" mean?  I couldn't find it in the online dictionaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more modern way to spell that would be *ēvolvēmus*: "we will unfold" the things that may follow from there. The form you're most likely to find in a dictionary is *ēvolvō*.

It's only recently that it's become common to distinguish the vowel *u* from the consonant *v*, and many editions still don't distinguish *i* from *j*, or long *ē* from short *e*.